# Faceted search and panels

Tags: 6, panels, search

I'm using [Faceted Search module](http://drupal.org/project/faceted_search) and i was trying to change a display of search result with Panels.

I've enabled `search-node` page in `admin/build/pages` and added a variant with URL selection rule set to `search/results/*` but it looks like nothing happens.
I'm still seeing default results page instead the one which uses Panels.

Am i doing something wrong? Does anyone have any tips?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the selection rule. If the page is active and has a variant, I would expect it to work without a path selection rule.